# How to put a contact form inside the footer of all the articles and pages of a website?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have a Contact Form 7 form inside a WP website. I want to insert this form at the end of every page and article of the website, near the copyright notice.

I just know the short code of the form (it works well inside a specific post):

```
[contact-form-7 id="42" title="Formular de contact"]
```

Having the short code I think that the question is not off-topic. I have basic knowledge of PHP and JavaScript.

I have searched Google a little and I still do not know how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add contact form shortcode in footer.php via use do_shortcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="42" title="Formular de contact"]') ?>
```